# Is there any way to prevent AlpineJS from slowing down my page speed?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, alpine.js

AlpineJS is decreasing my page speed (https://pagespeed.web.dev) from 95 to ~75-80. Is there anything I can do?

I've tried deferring the scripts and placing them in `<head>`, but the effect is not much different than simply placing them at the end of `<body>`.

I've also tried placing the JS inline but that doesn't speed anything up.

Other ideas? Is there anything else I can here do to defer Alpine?

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/siema@1.5.1/dist/siema.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/intersect@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/collapse@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/focus-visible@5.2.0/dist/focus-visible.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.10.5/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What units are you using for `95 to ~75-80` and how is this measured?

Comment: https://pagespeed.web.dev/

Comment: Is this happening purely from loading these CDNs? If that's the case, you're probably better off installing them via NPM, as it won't need to retrieve any off-site data.

Comment: Adding front-end interactivity via JS, jQuery, Alpine or whatever-js-library/framework is always going to have an impact on speed. Sometimes little, sometimes not so little, but there's no way to get back to 95.

Comment: Yes, the impact is purely due to the CDNs, according to Google Page Speed. Don't think I can install via npm because I'm using django templates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `defer` to the script tag?

```
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.10.5/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```

Also to accurately judge AlpineJS influence on the speed score try removing all the other plugins and scripts.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. The Alpine scripts are our only scripts. When I remove the Alpine scripts, page speed jumps to 95.

Comment: Same issue here, I'm asuming this is a structual problem with AlpineJS: https://www.erwinhofman.com/blog/3-reasons-why-alpinejs-wont-beat-jquery-core-web-vitals-included